# Maximum OR value of 2D Array of bits

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, bit-manipulation, dynamic-programming

Suppose there is a 2D array `(m x n)` of bits.

For example:

```
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0 
1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

here, `m = 4`, `n = 5`.

I can flip (`0` becomes `1`, `1` becomes `0`) the bits in any row. When you flip the bits in a particular row, you flip *all* the bits.

My goal is to get the max `OR` value between a given pair of rows.

That is, if the given pair of rows is `(r1, r2)`, then I can flip any number of rows between `r1` and `r2`, and I should find the maximum possible `OR` value of all the rows between `r1` and `r2`.

In the above example (consider arrays with 1-based index), if `r1` = 1 and `r2` = 4, I can flip the 1st row to get `0 1 1 0 1`. Now, if I find the `OR` value of all the rows from 1 to 4, I get the value `31` as the maximum possible `OR` value (there can be other solutions).

Also, it would be nice to to compute the answer for `(r1, r1)`, `(r1, r1+1)`, `(r1, r1+2)`, ... , `(r1, r2-1)` while calculating the same for `(r1,r2)`.

**Constraints**

`1 <= m x n <= 10^6`

`1 <= r1 <= r2 <= m`

A simple brute force solution would have a time complexity of `O(2^m)`.
Is there a faster way to compute this?

Comment: What is the application of this algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand how you come to O(2^m), a naive iteration on pairs of rows would rather be O(m*n^2) if you perform ops bit by bit, or O(n^2) if m <= sizeof(some_machine_integer) because the processor would perform the bitops in parallel, no?

Comment: @aka.nice Since there are m rows, I can chose nC0, nC1, nC2, nC3, ..., nCn rows to be flipped. Now, nC0 + nC1 + nC2 + nC3 + ... + nCn = 2^n.

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria ah now I get it, first I have inverted m & n, and second, you can OR any number of rows, not only a pair of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Since `A <= A | B`, the value of a number A will only go up as we `OR` more numbers to A.

Therefore, we can use binary search.

We can use a function to get the maximum between two rows and save the `OR`ed result as a third row. Then compare two of these third rows to get a higher-level row, and then compare two of these higher-level rows, and so on, until only one is left.

Using your example:

```
array1 = 1 0 0 1 0 [0]
         1 0 1 0 0 [1]
         1 0 1 1 0 [2]
         0 0 0 0 1 [3]

array2 = 1 1 0 1 1 <-- [0] | ~[1]
         1 1 1 1 0 <-- [2] | ~[3]

array3 = 1 1 1 1 1 <-- [0] | [1]
```

And obviously you can truncate branches as necessary when `m` is not a power of 2.

So this would be `O(m)` time. And keep in mind that for large numbers of rows, there are likely not unique solutions. More than likely, the result would be `2 ^ n - 1`.

**An important optimization**: If `m >= n`, then the output must be `2 ^ n - 1`. Suppose we have two numbers A and B. If B has `k` number missing bits, then `A` or `~A` will be guaranteed to fill at least one of those bits. By a similar token, if `m >= log n`, then the output must also be `2 ^ n - 1` since each `A` or `~A` is guaranteed to fill at least half of the unfilled bits in `B`.

Using these shortcuts, you can get away with a brute-force search if you wanted. I'm not 100% the binary search algorithm works in every single case.

Comment: How do you decide which row to `~`?

Comment: Just check all four combinations. It could be both that need to be `~`.

Comment: Consider 100 rows, in that case there would be 2^50 combinations for both upper and lower halves of the matrix.

Comment: No. 50 pairs for the first layer of comparisons, 25 for the second layer, 13 for the third, and so on. Approx. 100 total.

Comment: You mean that we'll compare only in pairs? How can we say that `nth` row has no effect on `(n+2)th` row?

Comment: You will get `O(n^2)` doing the algorithm above over `n` intervals. Just repeat the algorithm for each interval you want.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the problem of flipping the rows in the entire matrix and then or-ing them together to get as many 1s as possible, I claim this is tractable when the number of columns is less than 2^m, where m is the number of rows. Consider the rows one by one. At stage i counting from 0 you have less than 2^(m-i) zeros to fill. Because flipping a row turns 0s into 1s and vice versa, either the current row or the flipped row will fill in at least half of those zeros. When you have worked through all the rows, you will have less than 1 zeros to fill, so this procedure is guaranteed to provide a perfect answer.

I claim this is tractable when the number of columns is at least 2^m, where m is the number of rows. There are 2^m possible patterns of flipped rows, but this is only O(N) where N is the number of columns. So trying all possible patterns of flipped rows gives you an O(N^2) algorithm in this case.